# UI not updating when BindingList<> changes

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, bindinglist

I'm doubting I get a response on SO for this but I'm at my wit's end so here's hoping.

I have a `BindingList<myObj>` and a `BindingSource` on my form with it's `DataSource` set to the BindingList.  I then have a [Resco Mobile Controls](http://www.resco.net/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx) `UIListView` displaying this data.

On startup it displays just fine, data is bound properly and all but when I update any data it is never shown in the UI.  I have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented on `myObj` and have no idea what else I should be looking for....

This is all on Windows CE 6 with .NET CF 3.5.  Any ideas would be appreciated as I have been looking at this for a while now.

Comment: Are you, by chance, coming from a WPF background into WinForms on CF?

Comment: Yup but I have used Winforms a decent amount just not CF....

Answer (score 3):

Call when need to update:

```
bindingList.ResetBindings();
```

Comment: did not update the View

Comment: For anyone in the future trying to get WPF ListViews bound to BindingLists to refresh after NotifyPropertyChanged for one or more of the items, this worked for me, specifically by adding it after the operation was called.

Answer (score 2):

Usually what happens with the BindingList implementations is that only notify changes from add and delete actions, do not get notified on update of an item. I should recommend the use of ObservableCollection that notify the item changes.
a similar post here.
[Binding List and UI controls, not updating on edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020221/binding-list-and-ui-controls-not-updating-on-edit)
Regards, Pedro Morales.

Comment: Thanks, I might be wrong but I don't think `ObservableCollection` is an option in .NET CF....

Answer (score 2):

I solved it modifying the collection from the main thread, if I change it from a secondary thread the changes are not updated in the grid. (Even calling currencyManager Refresh or DataGrid Refresh)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take stab at this since you may not be getting a ton of traffic.

Have you tried getting the CurrencyManager and calling its refresh method? See the following:

[CurrencyManager.Refresh()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Combining a few of the answers here got me to my solution.  If you're not on the UI thread, you need to use an Invoke to call your refresh on UI thread instead.

```
Public Sub RefreshMyBoundList()
    If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf RefreshMyBoundList))
        Return
    End If
    MyBoundList.ResetBindings()
End Sub
```